# Maximum value in the track bar

Tags: c#, button, trackbar

I have a button that adds +100 to the track Bar.
Maximum value 43000, if the value is at 43000 and clicking the button will give error.

> Value '43001' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' must be between 'Minimum' and 'Maximum'.

```
private void button41_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{
    trackBar1.Value = trackBar1.Value += 100;      
    label27.Text = "" + trackBar1.Value; 
}
```

> *Issue resolved:*

```
  public Form1()
        {
            me = this;
            InitializeComponent();
            trackBar1.Maximum = 43000;
            trackBar1.Minimum = 40;


        }
```

button

```
private void button41_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (trackBar1.Value + 100 <= trackBar1.Maximum)
    {
         trackBar1.Value = trackBar1.Value += 100;
        label27.Text = "Frequency = " + trackBar1.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Max value = " + trackBar1.Maximum);
    }
}
```

[42990 + 100 without errors if I click add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXi7I.png)

[Message displayed when trying add more than the supported value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjiwV.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message already says all: The value may not be greater than the max-value.

Just add a condition before you increment the value:

```
if (trackBar1.Value < trackBar1.Maximum)
    trackBar1.Value++;
```

Or here your complete event handler:

```
private void button41_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (trackBar1.Value < trackBar1.Maximum)
    {
        trackBar1.Value++;
        label27.Text = trackBar1.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Max value = " + trackBar1.Maximum);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the number is in 42990 I try to put +100 would give error so I did it  (trackBar1.Value +100  < trackBar1.Maximum )